# In an HTML-based email, how would one handle bracket characters?

Tags: html, email, content-type

Let's say you've got an automated email that goes out with temporary passwords, and the < > characters can be used in the password.

How would you continue to use HTML email for this purpose and also prevent those characters from breaking the rest of the email?

Comment: Use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`. https://html.com/character-codes/

Answer (score 1):

if your using php you can use the function `htmlspecialchars()`
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php

It convert special characters to HTML entities